# Rails export and import object with relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new with Ruby and Rails.

Is there any simple way to export from one instance of application one object with 2 related models and import it to another?

Structure is:

```
- Model1
- - Model1 has many Model2
- - - Model2 has many Model3
```

Or may be is there any way to export/import MySql records?

Comment: you can use `has_many :through`, or use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, what do you mean exactly with import object ?

Comment: @MohamedYakout I have two instances of application (development and production) I upload data to my development instance of application from gpx file and later deleted this file. Now I can't simply upload this file to production, but need this data, so I'm looking for way to import/export data from one instance to another

Answer (score 1):

You have to build it yourself. This looks like a data dump (backup services or CSV dumps). You also can dump it as JSON.

Comment: Please, read my comment under question. My question is not about API and SOAP web services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that:

```
@new_model1 = @model1.includes(:model2 => [:models3]).clone
@new_model.save()
```

For switching connection between database you can use **magic connection**

Comment: I'm not sure I can do it because development instance hosts on my laptop, production - on VPS

Comment: May be is there any way to serialize to some format @new_model and save it to file? So I can upload it to VPS and in console read and save data to db?